# MySQL - One SQL request instead two (both request include diffrent COUNT(*)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

Once again i need yours help ;). I have a lot data and mysql request are slower and slower so the need request that i need i want group in one comand.

My example DB structure:

```
|product|opinion (pos/neg)|reason|
__________________________________
|milk   | pos             | good |
|milk   | pos             |fresh |
|chocolate| neg           | old  |
|milk   | neg             | from cow|
```

So i need information about all diffrent product (GROUP BY) count of it, and count of pos opinion for each product. I want output like that:

```
|product|count|pos count|
_________________________
|milk   |  3  | 2       |
|chocolate| 1 |  0      |
```

I hope that my explain was good enought ;)
Or go to work:  I write two commands

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as pos count FROM table WHERE product = "milk" AND opinion = "pos" GROUP BY `opinion`
```

And Second one

```
SELECT product, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY `product`
```

I don't know how to join this two request, maybe that is impossible? In my real use code i have additional category collumn and i use WHERE in second command too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select product, 
       count(*) as total_count
       sum(
         case when opinion='pos' then 1 
         else 0 end
       ) as pos_count
from the_table
group by product;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  product,
        COUNT(*) TotalCount,
        SUM(opinion = 'pos') POSCount
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY product
```

`SUM(opinion = 'pos')` is `MySQL` specific syntax that counts the total of result based from the result of boolean arithmethic. If you want it to be more RDBMS friends, use `CASE`

```
SUM(CASE WHEN opinion = 'pos' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84fad/1)

Comment: Thanks! That is it i can't tag this answer as my accepted but when i have enoght rep i will vote up ;)

Comment: Another short one not MySQL specific: COUNT(NULLIF(opinion,'pos')).  I still prefer the long version which is easier to understand :-)